# Leaflet with MarkerCluster: How to add/remove markers from cluster at the time of spideriying?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working on a Leaflet project, which can have quite a few markers on the map. The behavior that I have currently is, if you click on any of the cluster it will spiderify to show all the marker and the user can hover over individual markers to see more information about it. As the number of markers can be somewhere around 100 - 10K it can be a real issue to show all of them.

Theoretically, I would like to show 9 items and 1 items which will be kind of `More` marker containing information about the rest of the marker, which can be clicked which would lead to a different page.

My current implementation looks like this on `clustermouseover`.

```js
private createMarkerClusterGroup() {
  if (this.markerClusterGroup) { return; }
  this.markerClusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup(this.effectiveMarkerClusterGroupOptions);

  this.markerClusterGroup.on('clusterclick', (event: any) => {
    const cluster: ExtendedMarkerCluster = event.layer;
    event.layer.spiderfy();
  });
```

Few of the things I have been able to figure out are :-

- I can get the total children markers using `const markersCount = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();`
- I will have to remove all the extra markers and set the new markers location equal to any one of the removed markers and set a key with all the id's for them to be retrieved afterwards.

I am unable to put them together and make them work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of similar problem once. I resorted to showing a popup containing all of the markers rendered in a list as it was more clear to see. From what I recall I also had to render each marker with a `data-id` attribute, just to be able to get the data needed for tendering the popup.
Let me know if this helps a bit and don't hesitate to ask for more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am doing that as well. I do the popup thing on hover over cluster, and spiderify on the click. On popup I show list top values for the clusters and some graphs. I still need to figure out the solution for spiderify and cluster thing.

Comment: I get it. Hiding markers should be doable even if by adding a CSS class. As for the extra marker I have a wild idea. What if you try adding (as well with CSS) an after rule displaying your "see more" link?